# How to implement Python's multiprocessing Pool to convert thousands of files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multiprocessing, file-conversion

I have a Python script that reads in a directory containing over 10,000 DBF files so they can be converted to CSV. I would like to parellelize this task rather than converting each file individually. I have read up on Python's multiprocessing module, though I am having a little bit of trouble implementing it for this task. Specifically, I wanted to use the Pool class to distribute the workload across the CPU cores.

Here is my code thus far:

```
import os
from dbfread import DBF
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing

directory = 'C:\\Path_to_DBF_Files' #define file directory 

files_in = os.listdir(directory) #store files in directory to list 

def convert():

    for file in files_in:

        if file.startswith('D') and file.endswith('.DBF'): #define parameters of filenames to convert
            file_path = os.path.join(files_in, file)
            print(f'\nReading in {file}...')
            dbf = DBF(file_path) #create DBF object 
            dbf.encoding = 'utf-8' #set encoding attribute to utf-8 instead of acsii 
            dbf.char_decode_errors = 'ignore' #set decoding errors attribute to ignore any errors and read in DBF file as is 
            print('\nConverting to DataFrame...')
            df = pd.DataFrame(iter(dbf)) #convert to Pandas dataframe 
            df.columns.astype(str) #convert column datatypes to string
            print(df)
            print('\nWriting to CSV...')
            dest_directory = 'C:\\Path_to_output_directory\\%s.csv' % ('D' + file.strip('.DBF')) #define destination directory and names for output files 
            df.to_csv(dest_directory, index = False)
            print(f'\nConverted {file} to CSV. Moving to next file...')


        elif file.startswith('B') and file.endswith('.DBF'): #define parameters for unnecessary files 
            print('\nB file not needed.')
            continue

        elif file.endswith('.FPT'): #skip FPT files 
            print('Skipping FPT file.')
            continue

        elif file.startswith('ID') and file.endswith('.DB~'): #stop iteration when this file is reached in the directory 
            print('All files converted to CSV.')
            break

        else:
            print('\nFile not found or error.')
            print(f'Last file read in was {file}.')

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = len(in_files)) #create Pool to run across the length of the input directory
result = pool.map(convert, files_in) #reference convert function and list of DBF files to be passed through
print(result)
```

I've read a few answers here on StackOverflow that are somewhat similar to my question; however, I've not seen anything that applies to my specific task. How could I improve my code so that instead of reading and converting just one file at a time, the script will process multiple files simultaneously?

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: Here's my example on the topic, almost too heavily documented: https://gist.github.com/ltpitt/6cdcb5377c462445a315703c5062397c

Answer (score 2):

Some general guidance:

1. You are creating a pool. The pool size should depend on machine, not the size of your job. For example, you want 4 processes in the pool instead of 10000 processes even you have 10000 files to process
2. The job to run on each process should be simple but parameterized. In your case, create a function to take a filename as input and do the conversion. Then map input files into it. The filtering should be done before `map` is called.

So I would convert your code into something like the follows:

```py
import os
from dbfread import DBF
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing

directory = 'C:\\Path_to_DBF_Files' #define file directory 

files_in = os.listdir(directory) #store files in directory to list 

def convert(file):
    file_path = os.path.join(files_in, file)
    print(f'\nReading in {file}...')
    dbf = DBF(file_path) #create DBF object 
    dbf.encoding = 'utf-8' #set encoding attribute to utf-8 instead of acsii 
    dbf.char_decode_errors = 'ignore' #set decoding errors attribute to ignore any errors and read in DBF file as is 
    print('\nConverting to DataFrame...')
    df = pd.DataFrame(iter(dbf)) #convert to Pandas dataframe 
    df.columns.astype(str) #convert column datatypes to string
    print(df)
    print('\nWriting to CSV...')
    dest_directory = 'C:\\Path_to_output_directory\\%s.csv' % ('D' + file.strip('.DBF')) #define destination directory and names for output files 
    df.to_csv(dest_directory, index = False)
    print(f'\nConverted {file} to CSV. Moving to next file...')

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 4)
pool.map(convert, [file for file in files_in if file.startswith('D') and file.endswith('.DBF')])
```

Comment: That's a good answer. I'd probably use `glob` to list files, this one uses too many pixels ;)

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I swear by the `pathlib` library. people really need to stop using `os.path`. Upvote

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at the `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ProcessPoolExecutor`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

You can create a pool with an arbitrary amount of workers, submit the work while collecting the futures, and then waiting on them until they are all completed.

Refactor your convert function to process a single file (meaning, extract the for-loop form the function), then loop over the items while submitting the work.

Example code

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)

futures = []
for f in files:
    futures.append(executor.submit(convert, f)

for future in futures:
    future.result()
```

Comment: Isn't `ThreadPoolExecutor` blocked by GIL? As in, you don't really speed things up by using multiple cores, you simply execute stuff async.

Comment: Correct, but based [on this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515123/pandas-concurrent-futures-and-the-gil), `Pandas` should release the GIL. As Pandas is used in the example code, it should work. The alternative, as mentioned, is to use `ProcessPoolExecutor`

Comment: @GalacticDessert this is a good approach, but I wouldn't rely on threads, yes, pandas sometimes does strive to release the GIL in certain methods, AFAIK it isn't guaranteed. And you have to keep in mind, it isn't always obvious where, and can depend on options passed to methods. And since multiprocessing is suited here, I think it isn't a bad idea to just use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` here in the exact same way. That's a nice thing about `concurrent.futures`

Comment: Edited the answer to suggest `ProcessPoolExecutor`